# initialize array of arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby

When we initialize an array of arrays using

```
ar = Array.new(2, [0, -1])
```

It creates an array which looks like  **[[0, -1], [0, -1]]**

But when we change the value in the inner array, it gets reflected in all elements of the array.

```
ar[0][0] = 5
puts ar
```

> [[5, -1], [5, -1]]

Seems the same object is getting inserted into each index of the outer array. What is the correct way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Array.new block form](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new):

```rb
ar = Array.new(2) { [0, -1] }
```

Since the array literal `[0, -1]` is scoped to the block, a new instance is created on every invocation.  You can test this by adding a `puts` or similar in the block:

```rb
ar = Array.new(2) { |n| puts "called for element #{n}"; [0, -1] }
```

results in:

```
called for element 0
called for element 1
=> [[0, -1], [0, -1]]
```